# Keras Reshape doesn't seem to run

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, reshape

I have a simple convolutional autoencoder in keras. My original inputs are flat arrays from a csv, so I want to reshape them from (196,) to (14,14,1). Following the keras docs, I did:

```
autoencoder = Sequential()
# first, reshape our (csv) inputs from (196,) to (14,14,1)
autoencoder.add(Reshape((14,14,1), input_shape=(196,)))
# encoding stage
autoencoder.add(Conv2D(16, (3,3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
autoencoder.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same'))
autoencoder.add(Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
autoencoder.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same'))
autoencoder.add(Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
autoencoder.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same'))
# decoding stage
autoencoder.add(Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
autoencoder.add(UpSampling2D((2, 2)))
autoencoder.add(Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
autoencoder.add(UpSampling2D((2, 2)))
autoencoder.add(Conv2D(16, (2, 2), activation='relu'))
autoencoder.add(UpSampling2D((2, 2)))
autoencoder.add(Conv2D(1, (3, 3), activation='sigmoid', padding='same'))

optimizer = optimizers.Adagrad(lr=0.01, epsilon=None, decay=0.001)
autoencoder.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss='binary_crossentropy')
```

But I get the error: `ValueError: Error when checking target: expected conv2d_35 to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (2870, 196)`

So it seems to be ignoring the Reshape entirely. Am I making some obvious mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not the input but the **target** so the `y` values you give are not reshaped. The final output of your network is a 4D tensor where you give instead `(2870, 196)`.

Double check the your target array (y values) that you pass onto fit function.

Comment: Okay, yes, that completely makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: Quick follow-up question: is there a way to reshape my output? I can't get Reshape(196,) to work—it complains with `TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
`. I tried a Lambda example I found elsewhere, but coreml (my final destination) won't convert Lambda layers.